# Shell Script : How to detect if source list have a missing data for the distination list

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed, diff

I want to detect values in Data1 not included in Data2. 
I have 2 variables which contains:

```
Data1="PF10_SBCA-B
PF5_SBCA-G
PF10_SBCE-F
PF10_SBCC-W"

Data2="PF5_SBCA-B
PF10_SBCE-F
PF10_SBCA-B
PF5_SBCC-W"
```

**I try**

```
res=$(diff <(echo "$Data1") <(echo "$Data2"));
echo "$res"
```

**I get**

```
1c1,4
<
---
> PF5_SBCA-B
> PF10_SBCE-F
> PF10_SBCA-B
> PF5_SBCC-W
```

**instead of**

```
PF5_SBCA-G
PF10_SBCC-W
```

Please Help. Thank you

Comment: It might be important to mention which version of `diff` you're using, because [I'm not getting the same output as you do](https://ideone.com/zsWJku).

Comment: Try sorting the inputs. eg `diff <( echo "$Data1" | sort ) <( echo "$Data2" | sort)`.  Doesn't give you exactly what you want, though.

Comment: i have like this output : PF10_SBCA-B
PF10_SBCE-F
PF5_SBCA-B
PF5_SBCC-W
PF10_SBCA-B
PF10_SBCC-W
PF10_SBCE-F
PF5_SBCA-G

Comment: @WilliamPursell was close -- use `comm` instead of `diff` though.   (I'd post an answer, but @RomanPerekhrest beat me to it).

Answer (score 4):

Simply with **`comm`** + **`sort`** commands:

```
comm -23 <(sort <<<"$Data1") <(sort <<<"$Data2")
```

The output:

```
PF10_SBCC-W
PF5_SBCA-G
```

---

The synopsis: `comm [OPTION]... FILE1 FILE2`

- `-2` - suppress column 2 (lines unique to `FILE2`)
- `-3` - suppress column 3 (lines that appear in both files)

The lines unique to `FILE1` will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to read the values in the second list into an associative array, then check the values from the first list against the array.

```
declare -A data2
while IFS= read -r key; do
    data2[$key]=
done <<< "$Data2"

while IFS= read -r key; do
    [[ -v data2[$key] ]] || echo "$key not in Data2"
done <<< "$Data1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply loop on the values in $Data1 and check if they are present in $Data2:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
Data1="PF10_SBCA-B
       PF5_SBCA-G
       PF10_SBCE-F
       PF10_SBCC-W"

Data2="PF5_SBCA-B
       PF10_SBCE-F
       PF10_SBCA-B
       PF5_SBCC-W"

for value in $Data1
do
    if [ $(echo $Data2 | grep -c $value) -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo $value
    fi
done
```

Output:

```
PF5_SBCA-G
PF10_SBCC-W
```